# Get windows list from primary screen only

Tags: c#, multiple-monitors

How can I get list of windows from primary screen only on multi-monitor configuration?

I'm trying to use the `EnumDesktopWindows` method of the windows api through pinvoke:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "EnumDesktopWindows", ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] 
public static extern bool EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr hDesktop, EnumDelegate lpEnumCallbackFunction, IntPtr lParam);
```

Comment: In your application, or is this UI automation?

Comment: Have 3 monitors. User can randomly set anyone as primary.
I'm use some code like this: 
                EnumDelegate filter = delegate (IntPtr hWnd, int lParam)
                {
                    StringBuilder strbTitle = new StringBuilder(255);
                    int nLength = GetWindowText(hWnd, strbTitle, strbTitle.Capacity + 1);
                    string strTitle = strbTitle.ToString();
...
but need filter windows list and select it only for primary monitor.
Does window have property with monitor type or number?

Answer (score 0):

Just get primary screen bounds, then check windows coordinates:

```
foreach (var screen in Screen.AllScreens)
{if (screen.Primary) return screen.Bounds;}
```